# call a angular directive from controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a mobi scroll date picker and i have done the age validation using directive.
I am doing multi step form validation for the signup process. How do i call the directive again(i.e age validation) if i click on the back button.

```
<input type="text" id="dateOfBirth" placeholder="Please Select ..."  data-ng-model="personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob" name="dob" ng-required="true" age-valid mobi-date=true />
```

### directive

```
.directive('ageValid', ['$filter', function($filter) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',        
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$validators.validAge = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        var todayDate = new Date(),
          todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear(),
          todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth(),
          todayDay = todayDate.getDate(),
          dateFieldVal = viewValue,
          birthYear = viewValue.split('/')[2],
          birthMonth = viewValue.split('/')[1],
          birthDay = viewValue.split('/')[0],
          age = todayYear - parseInt(birthYear);

          if(todayMonth < parseInt(birthMonth) - 1){
            age--;
          }
          if(parseInt(birthMonth) - 1 === todayMonth && todayDay < parseInt(birthDay)){
            age--;
          }                  
          return age >= 21;
      };
    } 
  }
}])
```

### controller

```
$scope.backbutton = function(){

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U should use a factory as an intermediate like:

**DIRECTIVE:**

```
.directive('ageValid', ['$filter','Age', function($filter,Age) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',        
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$validators.validAge = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
       return Age.ageValidation(modelValue, viewValue);
      };
    } 
  }
}])
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.backbutton = function(){

};
```

**Factory:**

```
.factory("Age", function (NombresGuardado) {

    return {
        ageValidation: function (modelValue, viewValue) {
             var todayDate = new Date(),
              todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear(),
              todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth(),
              todayDay = todayDate.getDate(),
              dateFieldVal = viewValue,
              birthYear = viewValue.split('/')[2],
              birthMonth = viewValue.split('/')[1],
              birthDay = viewValue.split('/')[0],
              age = todayYear - parseInt(birthYear);

              if(todayMonth < parseInt(birthMonth) - 1){
                age--;
              }
              if(parseInt(birthMonth) - 1 === todayMonth && todayDay < parseInt(birthDay)){
                age--;
              }                  
              return age >= 21;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the controller scope from your directive. In your case, you use the same scope from your directive (by not specifying the `scope`property), so your code may look like =>

```js
// Directive

.directive('ageValid', ['$filter', function($filter) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',        
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.doSomething = function() {
        console.log("hello");
      }
    } 
  }
}])

// Controller

$scope.backbutton = function(){
  $scope.doSomething();
};
```